# Is there a limit to the difference between the boiling and melting points of any material?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

Is there a mathematical limit to the difference in the temperatures,  a substance acquires before changing states, in this particular case,  is there a limit to  the difference between the boiling and melting points of an element or a compund?

Comment: You mean an upper bound to the difference? Of course. A million billion kelvin would certainly be an upper bound. The *smallest* upper bound, however, won't be known since there are plenty of materials we have yet to study/create.

Comment: No, for instance the 100 K gap for water the near 2000 K gap for gallium, how far does this difference proceed? Is there any sort of symmetry to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the melting point and especially the boiling point of a substance depend on the pressure you had to specify a pressure. Also not all substances do have a melting or boiling point. Some, e.g. carbon at standard pressure sublimate.

A good canditate for the substance with the highest difference at standard pressure is neptunium with a value above 3200 K.